# Multiple Jar file not found issues with IBM watson personality Insights

Tags: java, watson, personality-insights

I'm writing a watson program to fetch personality traits. However, I'm running into errors with jar file issues.

```
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3.PersonalityInsights;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3.model.Profile;

public JSONArray getPersonalityTraitsFromWatson(String text) {

    JSONArray retval = null;
    PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights("2016-10-20", "xxxx", "yyyy");
    Profile response = service.getProfile(text).execute();
    System.out.println("profile: " + response);

    return retval; 
}
```

The first problem is with okhttp3. I get a classnotfound error with JavaNetCookieJar. I'm currently using okhttp3 and javanetcookiejar is missing in it. I picked up the okhttp3 from MVNRepository.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/JavaNetCookieJar
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.configureHttpClient(WatsonService.java:137)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.<init>(WatsonService.java:117)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3.PersonalityInsights.<init>(PersonalityInsights.java:52)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3.PersonalityInsights.<init>(PersonalityInsights.java:70)
    at com.xyz.social.Watson.getPersonalityTraitsFromWatson(Watson.java:20)
    at com.xyz.Testing.UnitTester.startUnitTest(UnitTester.java:1720)
    at com.xyz.Testing.UnitTester.main(UnitTester.java:1850)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I tried using "org.apache.servicemix.bundles.okhttp-3.2.0_1.jar" with and with the okhttp3.jar which clears the JavaNetCookieJar error but throws an SSLSocketFactory error (given below)

okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;Ljavax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager;)

Comment: Found the problem, the okhttp-urlconnection-3.8.1.jar & logging-interceptor-3.8.1.jar were required to be added. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the okhttp-urlconnection-3.8.1.jar & logging-interceptor-3.8.1.jar were required to be added. This fixed the problem.